# How can I cycle through the children of the children in an XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I can get the version date and version number to show up, but for the remaining information I want it to output the element name followed by the information within the tag. In the end I'd like it to read something like:

```
versionDate: 2011-10-04
versionNumber: 1.0
FirstName: Bob 
LastName: Johnson
PhoneNumber: 123-456-7890
FaxNumber: 111-111-1111
EmailAddress: bjohnson@aol.com
Gender: M
FirstName: Sue 
LastName: Smith
PhoneNumber: 987-654-3210
FaxNumber: 222-222-2222
EmailAddress: ssmith@comcast.net
Gender: F
```

Instead, it's displaying this:

```
versionDate: 2011-10-04
versionNumber: 1.0
versionDate#text - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04versionNumber#text - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04ContactFirstName - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04ContactFirstName - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04ContactFirstName - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04ContactFirstName - 2011-10-04Contact info: False#text - 2011-10-04ContactFirstName - 2011-10-04Contact info:
```

I've tried making another XmlNodeList that's a child of the child, but it's not liking the syntax, so I need to know how to get down to the next level of information.

I have attached the XML and C# file below.

```
<Contacts>
  <versionDate>2011-10-04</versionDate>
  <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
  <Contact Gender ="M">
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
    <PhoneNumber>123-456-7890</PhoneNumber>
    <FaxNumber>111-111-1111</FaxNumber>
    <EmailAddress>bjohnson@aol.com</EmailAddress>
  </Contact>
  <Contact Gender ="F">
    <FirstName>Sue</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <PhoneNumber>987-654-3210</PhoneNumber>
    <FaxNumber>222-222-2222</FaxNumber>
    <EmailAddress>ssmith@comcast.net</EmailAddress>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string results = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\XMLFile1.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
        XmlElement elm = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        results += elm.FirstChild.Name + ": " + elm.FirstChild.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
        results += elm.FirstChild.NextSibling.Name + ": " + elm.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;


        XmlNodeList contactInfo = elm.ChildNodes;
        for (int count = 0; count < contactInfo.Count; count++)
        {
            results += (contactInfo[count].Name);
              results += (contactInfo[count].FirstChild.Name + " - " + contactInfo[0].FirstChild.InnerText);
            results += ("Contact info: " + contactInfo[0].FirstChild.HasChildNodes.ToString());
            XmlNodeList contactProperties = contactInfo[0].ChildNodes;

            for (int counter = 0; counter < contactProperties.Count; counter++)
            {
                results += (contactProperties[counter].Name + " - " + contactProperties[counter].InnerText);

            }
        }

        textBox1.Text += results;
    }

}
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I tried to format your output, but I'm a little unsure what the exact output looks like. Please edit and format the output listing.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion should work:

```
public string CompileResults(XElement e)
{
    string retVal = String.Format("{0}:{1} ", e.Name, e.Value);

    foreach (XAttribute xa in e.Attributes())
        retVal += String.Format("{0}:{1} ", xa.Name, xa.Value);

    foreach (XElement xe in e.Elements())
        retVal += CompileResults(xe); ;
    return retVal;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\XMLFile1.xml";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(fileName);

    string results = CompileResults(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
}
```

Comment: Should consider StringBuilder if you're going to make a general-use method out of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
public static void DumpXml(XElement root, TextWriter writer)
{
    if (root.HasElements)
    {
        foreach (var child in root.Elements())
        {
            DumpXml(child, writer);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", root.Name, root.Value);
    }

    foreach (var attr in root.Attributes())
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var writer = new StringWriter();
DumpXml(doc.Root, writer);
var result = writer.ToString();
```